# Bootstrap Datetimepicker is not autoclosing

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

Bootstrap datetimepicker is not autoclosing on select of date.When I am selecting date from datetimepicker it should close the datetimepicker,but it is not closing

Comment: You have to add relevant code to show your issue and what you tried. Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) and learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input.datum').datepicker({  
  autoclose: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <label>Date:</label>
    <input class="datum" type="text" name="vondatum" required>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

You need add autoclose for this.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    autoclose: true     
});
```